# Are we lacking interesting Creative Common datasets?

Tags: dataset, survey

I and a group of fellows are currently self-teaching some statistical methods using online resources. We mainly use R to tinker with algorithms such as K-means clustering and linear regression. Personally, I come from a computer science background, thus I manly plot and compute over data originating from runs of computer software.

I found some interesting but small datasets about humans i.e. a dataset that provides samples on body mass index, obesity, blood pressure, sex and age. These data I found in particular more interesting since the use of linear regression makes immediate sense and can be interpreted even by a beginner like my.

Does anyone know about more general fitness data? Such as samples with sex, age, weight, minutes of activity per week, etc. Either I am really bad on googling lately or these data are somewhere deeply hidden on the web.

Nevertheless, as a computer scientist I thought it would be easy to just collect the data myself. Here is an attempt to do exactly that: https://steinbauer.org/2016/06/how-fit-are-you/